# Overlay lines and hist with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm creating a table with a lot of plot using ggplot

```
a=rnorm(30)
b=a*a
c=rnorm(30)
d=c
l=runif(30)
m=l+3
data=data.frame(A=a,B=b,ss=1)
data=rbind(data,data.frame(A=c,B=d,ss=2))

ggplot()+ geom_line(data=data,aes(A,B,group=ss),col="red")+facet_wrap(~ ss,as.table=T
```

In each of this plots I have to overlap an histogram. 
How can I do?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = data, aes(x = A, y = B), col = "red") +
  geom_histogram(data = data, aes(x = A), alpha = .5) +
  facet_wrap(~ ss,as.table=T)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I do if the element I have to hist has more rows than the elements in the data.frame?

Comment: @Donbeo First of all, an example should cover all critical points of the question. To answer your question: You could compute the histogram bars with the `hist` function and manually modify the heights of the bars. In this case, they have to be added with `geom_barplot`.

Comment: Ok thanks last question when I am using geom_histogram how can i set the probability on the y axe?  For example suppose to have 100 sample instead of see 60 I would like to see 0.6

Comment: @Donbeo `geom_histogram(data = data, aes(x = A, y = ..count../sum(..count..)), alpha = .5)` Of course, this only works if the histogram is plotted first.

Comment: sadly I cannot plot histogram . (I should change a quiet big program...) Is there another way to do that? Or at least is there any way do set the y axe value?